# sqoop auto create hive table comment when import mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop, sqoop

For now, I know I can use `--hive-import` option to tell hive to auto create the table in hive,but the auto-created table in hive doesn't contain comments which are in mysql table.

Is there a way to sync comments between hive tables and mysql tables?

To be exactly,I have following mysql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `current_day` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'order day',
  `total` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'total order'
);
```

I use following command to import to hive:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<mysql-host>:3306/xigua --username <user>  --password <pwd> --table orders --hive-import  -m 1
```

Then in hive I get following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders`(
  `current_day` string,
  `total` bigint)
COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2015/05/25 15:10:03'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to copy comments from mysql columns via sqoop. you could either add comments in the create statement or alter the table columns at a later stage and add the comments using this syntax:

`ALTER TABLE table_name [PARTITION partition_spec] CHANGE [COLUMN] col_old_name col_new_name column_type
  [COMMENT col_comment] [FIRST|AFTER column_name] [CASCADE|RESTRICT];`

You could automate this procedure with a script that queries your mysql table metadata and then uses that information to alter your hive table.